# jQuery height() differs from clientHeight

Tags: jquery, height

So I have an element:

```
<div class="obj">
  <img width="896" height="595" src... />
  <div class="details">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="obj">
  <img width="896" height="595" src... />
  <div class="details">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm then performing this on them:

```
$objs = $('.obj');
$objs.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).height());
}
```

In element inspector in Chrome, the height of .obj is 720 (same as the image). However I get  0 in the console for each element.

The images aren't floated, so the .obj is containing it's children in css. I don't really know what could be going wrong, and why jQuery isn't returning 720.

Could it be CSS related?

Answer (score 1):

It could be CSS related. Without posting your CSS, it's hard to know. (You say that Chrome reports the height of obj is 720, the same as the image, yet the height of the image is set to 595)?

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr4Ns/) shows how it does work.

Comment: I had 'height: auto;' in css which was over-riding it back to 0 in jQuery. Not sure that make sense to me, but I have ti fixed. The 720/595 issue was a typo btw, sorry. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Handle the window.onload event to ensure all images are loaded, ex.

```
$(window).load(
  function() {
    $objs = $('.obj');
    $objs.each(function() {
        console.log($(this).height());
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: The `ready()` handler is not related to the images being loaded. Use `$( window ).load( ... )` to ensure that they are loaded.